# SQLite, PHP - prepare method fail to prepare upsert query

Tags: php, sqlite, upsert

I have a [small project](https://github.com/TheSETJ/button-click-counter) in which I've written a PHP code that supposed to be an API. It simply counts clicks on a button.

In my API, I want to use SQLite to persist clicks count in a table named `stats`. In one of my functions in my API (`updateClicksCount`), after creating a new `SQLite3` instance and ensuring the existence of the table (with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` query), I try to prepare an [upsert query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) as follow:

```php
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO "stats" ("key", "value")
  VALUES (clicks_count, :count)
  ON CONFLICT("key") DO UPDATE SET "value" = :count');
```

But `prepare` returns `false` and complain about *syntax error near `ON`*. Though I can't find what's wrong with the query.

Comment: What is your SQLite version, upsert is added to SQLite from version 3.24.0

Comment: @catcon How can I check? I'm using [lando](https://lando.dev/) to set up my environment, mostly I'm using what is shipping by default. The only thing I'm aware of is that I'm using PHP v7.3.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://database.guide/check-sqlite-version/

Comment: @catcon SQLite version 3.16.2. So, there is no upsert. Ok. Can you suggest an alternative query that does the same? I've read about insert or replace, but it overwrites all values in a matching row, I don't want that.

Comment: @catcon It will be not clear for someone that will look at the code (including myself after some time) that what is the purpose of an insert after an update, but it seems there is no other way and it'll do the job. Thanks.